# Switching between HorizontalScrollView and BarChart scroll

Tags: java, android, mpandroidchart, horizontalscrollview

I have a MPAndroidChart BarChart which is placed inside a HorizontalScrollView. Now, I have multiple bars in the chart view and also the chart width is fixed as per my requirement. Since, there is a default scroll behaviour of chart, I can see all the bars.

The only problem is the scroll behaviour is not smooth and it lags a lot.

My idea is to disable the HorizontalScrollView once I start scrolling the chart and enable it back when I touch outside the chart. Can someone please tell me how I can do it? I hope my question is clear enough and there is no need to share any XML for it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced similar issue while using Mpchart inside horizontal scroll view.
I had a workaround with MpChart setOnChartGestureListener.

```
barChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new OnChartGestureListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChartGestureStart(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
            horizontalScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChartGestureEnd(MotionEvent me, ChartTouchListener.ChartGesture lastPerformedGesture) {
            horizontalScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }

        //.....//

        @Override
        public void onChartTranslate(MotionEvent me, float dX, float dY) {
            Log.i("GESTURE", "onChartTranslate");
            if(barChart.getLowestVisibleX() == barChart.getXAxis().getAxisMinimum() || barChart.getHighestVisibleX() == barChart.getXAxis().getAxisMaximum()) {
                horizontalScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
            } else {
                horizontalScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
            }
        }
    });
```

the horizontalScrollView object is where the chart reside.

Comment: I didn't get it, how did you use horizontalScrollView, how did you bind the scroll view with chart? I'm facing alot of lag issues while swiping the chart on x axis. If you can share more piece of code or help me with my issue that will be really appreaciated 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/72184522/8701110